# How to remove parent category from Yoast breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm having a bit of hard time trying to get this one link/category disappear from my bredcrumb path.

The path goes as follows: `home/customPostTypeCategory/subCategory/child/` , so what I need to get done is to get that `customPostTypeCategory` to go away.

So as a clearness, this is a **Custom post type** made with **Types** -plugin, and breadcrumbs are using **SEO by Yoast breadcrumbs**.

This could be done via CSS, but that is the last solution I'm willing to use.

Any clues, tips or tricks how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be an option in Yoast to strip category base, if you tick this go to settings -> permalinks and resave your permalinks

Comment: Thanks for a suggest, but it won't do the trick, cause it only removes the world 'category' in front of urls.

Comment: :( In that case try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this by using **jQuery** and **contains** -selector.

`$( "#breadcrumbs a:contains('customPostTypeCategory')" ).removeAttr( "href" );`

This obviously removes only the link, so that the category name still stays.

If the whole thing should be removed, then one could use the following:

`$( "#breadcrumbs a:contains('customPostTypeCategory')" ).css( "display", "none" );`

This did the trick for me, but it ain't the solution I was looking and asking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'my_breadcrumb_filter_function' );
function my_breadcrumb_filter_function( $crumbs ) {
    foreach( $crumbs as $i => $crumb ) {
        $term = get_object_vars($crumb['term']);
       if( isset( $term['parent'] ) && $term['parent'] != 0 ) {

        } else {
            $new_crumbs[] = $crumbs[$i];
        }
    }
    return $new_crumbs;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work either, but thanks anyway. Time for the heavy tools(jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a custom post type.

After looking at the output of the array, I saw that `array(1)` was the archive, and what I believe you're calling a category.

This did the trick for me:

```
function my_breadcrumb_filter_function( $crumbs ) {

    // replace "cpt" with your custom post type name 
    if(is_singular('cpt')) {
      $crumbs[1] = '';
    }
    return $crumbs;

}
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'my_breadcrumb_filter_function' );
```